# Sending a POST API request using PowerQuery on Excel/PBI with a request body?

Tags: excel, api, rest, powerquery, m

I am attempting to send a POST request using an API in PowerQuery on Excel/PBI. The request requires a body, and I've tried a few different ways (see below) but I keep recieving a DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://myapi.com/data' (400): Bad Request.

My request looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://myapi.com/data", [Headers=[#"X-Impersonate-User"="usr_12345", Authorization="Bearer tok_12345", #"Content-Type"="application/json"], 
    
    Content=Json.FromValue({[start_date="2022-08-01T08:00:00.000Z", end_date="2022-08-10T08:00:00.000Z", space_ids="spc_12345", time_resolution="day"]})


    ]))
in
    Source
```

I also tried it this way, but ran into the same issue:

```
let 
    url = "https://myapi.com/data"
    body = "{""start_date"" : ""2022-08-01T08:00:00.000Z"", ""end_date"" : ""2022-08-10T08:00:00.000Z"", ""space_ids"" : ""spc_12345"", ""time_resolution"" : ""day""}",
    Parsed_JSON = Json.Document(body),
    BuildQueryString = Uri.BuildQueryString(Parsed_JSON),
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/json", #"X-Impersonate-User"="usr_12345", Authorization="Bearer Bearer tok_12345"], Content = Text.ToBinary(BuildQueryString) ] ))
in
    Source
```

I am able to call the API from Postman with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

You want something closer to

```
let
    url = ...,
    headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/json"],
    postData = Json.FromValue(
        [
            start_date = "2022-08-01T08:00:00.000Z",
            end_date = "2022-08-10T08:00:00.000Z",
            space_ids = "spc_12345", 
            time_resolution = "day"            
        ]
    ),
    response = Web.Contents(
        url,
        [
            Headers = headers,
            Content = postData
        ]
    ),
    jsonResponse = Json.Document(response)
in
    jsonResponse
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the exact same error with that code.

Comment: Try an example like this, so that you have `Value.Metadata` on your jsonresponse. [ninMonkQuery-examples/WebContents_catch_errors.pq](https://github.com/ninmonkey/ninMonkQuery-examples/blob/main/WebRequests/pq/WebContents%20%E2%81%9E%20Catch%20uncatchable%20Datasource%20errors%E2%94%90main_query.pq) -- Don't do it all in a single step like `Json.Document(Web.Contents(` , because then the data is lost. -- So use that to check out the response headers, and the actual url/payload is right. 400 usually means your relativeUrl or json body is wrong. -- also explicitly use utf8